# How to select the Android Layout for desired design?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image, as below[image]

I made the above bar and buttons as below in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleRowId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/segment_bar_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/backBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_btn_bg"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/addBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bar_btn_bg"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="Done"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Convert Amount"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I do draw the buttons, according to following design, I face problem in aligments,
As I used TableLayout, and rows for displaying them, as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:binding="http://www.gueei.com/android-binding/"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|top"
        binding:text="FormattedDisplay"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textSize="45dip" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number7"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number8"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number9"
                android:text="9" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number4"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number5"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number6"
                android:text="6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number2"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Number3"
                android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                android:layout_span="2"
                binding:onClick="Number0"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Dot"
                android:text="." />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <Button
                binding:onClick="Equal"
                android:text="Convert" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but it not aligning the buttons properly

**how to resolve the issue and get desired output?**

**Can anyone tell me how to choose Layout, so that we can get proper output?**

XML output shows are

[image]

Comment: As the given image, I want like that @RajdeepDua

Comment: How are the two xml files related?

Comment: The issue is alignment of buttons, I have added the second image, that is output in android,

Comment: The first XML will generate the bar on top and two buttons,so that is ok, but what about buttons alignements, I can't solve that

Comment: See the size of 7,4 and 1 buttons, these are bigger than others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your `Convert Button` out of the `TableLayout` and paste it at last place inside `LinearLayout` after `TableLayout` as:

```
<LinearLayout ...  >
    <TextView/>
    <TableLayout>
        <TableRows etc>
    </TableLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        binding:onClick="Equal"
        android:text="Convert" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is giving me the result:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: The convert button can stay where it is the button must only have a attribute `android:layout_span="3"`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I think OP should consider it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open your XML layout file and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

After, open **Graphical Layout** Tab and add desired widgets at desired position. You will get all items as you need (e.g., as in above image you attached). try this. This is correct way for big layouts.

Comment: It will be issue in different devices, won't it?

Answer (score 0):

As not all buttons have the same width I would suggest using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). Using a RelativeLayout you can define your layout by telling each element how it should be positioned within the layout related to other elements. You can apply [attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) to the views within the relative layout like `android:layout_toLeftOf` or `android:layout_below` to define the position.

Comment: but what about width of button, if I will give manually, then on different devices, it will differ the output,

Comment: Mh ok I see. Then I would put the elements of each line into LinearLayout with orientation horizontal and work with the weight attribute. Using the weight attribute you can tell the views that they should share the existing space in a certain ratio.

Comment: can you give demo of two or three rows, as I am not clear about structures of android layout, just code a bit, I will see, as it is working or not

Comment: Check Adil Soomro answer, he's right. You can take you layout and simply adapt it little bit.